# Mapstruct Qualified By Name Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper

I have a Post Entity and a Post DTO, currently trying to map the DTO to Entity but it's giving me a `Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ getUserByUsername ].` Any help would be greatly appreciated, these are my current files:

PostDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PostDTO {

    private String author;

    @Size(max = 755)
    private String content;

}
```

Post Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "POSTS")
    private User author;

    @Column(name = "POSTED_AT", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @Size(max = 755)
    @Column(name = "CONTENT", nullable = false, length = 755)
    private String content;

}
```

PostMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses = {MappingUtil.class, PostRepository.class})
public interface PostMapper {

    // since the author attribute on postDTO is a String, we use mapstruct to find
    // within our database the matching user to that username and return the user object
    @Mapping(source = "author", target = "author", qualifiedByName = {"getUserByUsername"})
    Post toEntity(PostDTO postDTO);

    PostDTO toDTO(Post post);

}
```

MappingUtils:

```
@Component
public class MappingUtil {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    MappingUtil(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "getUserByUsername")
    public User getUserByUsername(String username){
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

So whenever I run the build, the mapper can't find the `@Named` annotation with the getUserByUsername method on the MappingUtil class, I've tried a few approaches but can't seem to fix it

Comment: do you have more than one class called `PostDTO` ? if somake sure your mapper is importing the class from the right package.

Comment: which version of mapstruct are you using? I'm having trouble reproducing at after using the `@Named` annotation in `MappingUtil`. Tried to reproduce with `1.3.1.Final`, `1.4.2.Final` and `1.5.0.Beta2`. Only options that I can really think of are that a different version than those is used, one of the imports is wrong, or perhaps a mismatch between mapstruct annotation version and mapstruct processor version.

Comment: Using default method in the interface worked for me. Access the spring repository layer code using Spring Context's `getBean()` method. eg. `SpringAppContext.getBean(UserRep.class).findByUserName(input)` in the interface's default method.

Comment: can you give us github scoped source code to reproduce this issue? such as pom file, your classes which lead to this issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotaion @BeanMapping doesn't help you. Use @Name instead and the error will be disappeared.

```
@Named("getUserByUsername")
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
```

Also you need a mapping for converting User to UserName in toDTO(Post post) like this:

```
@Mapping(source = "author.userName", target = "author")
PostDTO toDTO(Post post);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses = {MappingUtil.class, PostRepository.class})
public interface PostMapper {

    // since the author attribute on postDTO is a String, we use mapstruct to find
    // within our database the matching user to that username and return the user object
    @Mapping(source = "author", target = "author", qualifiedByName = "getUserByUsername")
    Post toEntity(PostDTO postDTO);

    PostDTO toDTO(Post post);

}

@Component
public class MappingUtil {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    MappingUtil(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Named("getUserByUsername")
    public User getUserByUsername(String username){
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

can you please try to use @Named annotation on your method. this would help map-struct find the method which it needs to run for mapping your field.

Comment: I did, still get the Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value:

Comment: @Padua are you using `org.mapstruct.Named` or some other `@Named`?

Comment: @Filip ```org.mapstruct.Named```

Answer (score -1):

Package private constructor ?
Try to add `public` to your constructor:

```
public MappingUtil(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Comment: setting constructor to public didn't work :(